# Stop Paypal recurring payment from paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i have successfully created recurring payment in sandbox mode(paypal).My simple question is how do i stop or cancel recurring payment from paypal.I logged in paypal sandbox and can see "You have a new automatic payment profile for aa Nanda " but can't stop or cancel.Actually i don't know from where cancel the payment.

Answer (score 0):

How do I cancel a subscription, recurring payment or automatic billing agreement?

Cancelling a subscription cancels all future scheduled payments of that subscription. A subscription can be cancelled up until three business days before the next scheduled payment.

> 1.Log in to your PayPal account.
>
> 2.Click Profile near the top of the page.
>
> 3.Click My money.
>
> 4.Click Update beside 'My pre-approved payments.'
>
> 5.Click the name of the subscription you wish to cancel.
>
> 6.Click Cancel.

this is from paypal documentation find it [here](https://www.paypal.com/helpcenter/main.jsp?t=solutionTab&ft=homeTab&ps=&solutionId=59055&locale=en_AU&_dyncharset=UTF-8&countrycode=AU&cmd=_help&m=BT)

Comment: 'My pre-approved payments.' page showing "There's no data available".but sandbox showing "You have a new automatic payment profile for aa Nanda".then why it happening